# Pass date parameter to dynamic sql

Tags: sql

I'm having a very hard time framing this query. The error is - *Conversion failed when converting date from character string.*
It is a generic query to work for all tables. All was working good, but i had to add a date parameter.

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @qryUpd nvarchar(MAX), @params nvarchar(MAX), @TableName nvarchar(50),
        @ColName nvarchar(50),@Id nvarchar(50),@ModifiedBy nvarchar(50),
        @ModifiedDate datetime


set @qry = 'update '+@TableName+' set Deleted=1, ModifiedBy='+''''+@Id+''',
            ModifiedDate='+''''+@ModifiedDate+''''+' where '+@Colname+'='+''''+
            @Id+''''

execute sp_executesql @qry
```

**C#:**

```
public void test(int id, int userid)
{
  sqlCommand cmd = new sqlcommand("TestFunc",con);
  cmd.commandtype = commandtype.storedprocedure;
  cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@TableName","tblArea");
  cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@ColName","AreaId");
  cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@Id",id);
  cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@ModifiedBy",userid);
  cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@ModifiedDate",system.datetime.now.tostring());
}
```

Comment: Well, `@ModifiedDate` is declared as a `DATETIME`, so you can't just concatenate it without converting it to a string (and yes, I know that you are passing `system.datetime.now.tostring()` from C# to your variable, but the variable is still a `DATETIME`). So, either declare `@ModifiedDate` as a `nvarchar` or do the necessary casting

Comment: Thank you everyone, but I was also testing directly in sql.Could you plz check if the sql query is all good. I am concerned about the many single quotes and would first like to make sure that this query is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the exception of the dynamic table name and the column, you can at least partially [parameterize](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx) your query, which will take away the headache of escaping quotes, and also give some protection against Sql Injection (since the table and column are still vulnerable and need to be validated):

```
DECLARE @qry AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @qry = N'update '+@TableName + 
            ' set Deleted=1, ModifiedBy=@ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate=@ModifiedDate
            where ' + @Colname + ' = @Id';
exec sp_executesql @qry, 
        N'@Id nvarchar(50), @ModifiedBy nvarchar(50), @ModifiedDate datetime', 
        @Id  = @Id,
        @ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy,
        @ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4474/8)

You can then bind your .Net parameters for `@Id, @ModifiedBy and @ModifiedDate` directly with the native types

Comment: The date param from c# will still be a string . right?

Comment: No, just bind it straight from a .Net DateTime - let ADO do all the heavy lifting :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the parameters in the wrong way. Use this:

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

set @ParmDefinition = '@Id int, @ModifiedDate datetime'

set @qry = 'update '+@TableName+' set Deleted=1, ModifiedBy=@Id, ModifiedDate=@ModifiedDate where ' + @Colname + '=@Id'

execute sp_executesql @qry, @ParmDefinition, @ModifiedDate, @Id
```

Also pass parameter as `DateTime` instead of `string` by removing the `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

The column `ModifiedDate`  is a `datetime` field then you must pass the value as a a `datetime` not as a string

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@ModifiedDate",DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your last C# row:

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@ModifiedDate",system.datetime.now.tostring());
```

with this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedDate",System.Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```